# AngularJS: Preventing 'mouseenter' event triggering on child elements

Tags: angularjs, mouseover, event-bubbling, mouseenter

I'm playing right now with the AngularJS framework and I stumbled upon a problem. I made a directive which is called 'enter'. It triggers functions on `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. I applied it as an attribute to the table row elements. It is now **triggered for every child element** (all the columns and etc), but it should be only triggered, when you go with your mouse over the table row.

This is how my directive looks like:

```
myapp.directive('enter', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A', // link to attribute... default is A
        link: function (scope, element){
            element.bind('mouseenter',function() {
                console.log('MOUSE ENTER: ' + scope.movie.title);
            });
            element.bind('mouseleave',function() {
                console.log('LEAVE');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Here is an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/dJGfd/1/

*You have to open the Javascript console to see the log messages.*

What is the best way to achieve the functionality that I want in AngularJS? I prefer to **not** use jQuery if there is a reasonable AngularJS solution.

Comment: That looks like a bug to me. Just a quick note, you can also apply the Angular directive called "ng-mouseenter" / "ng-mouseleave". My idea would be to save the last hovered element and see if it is different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this:

```
myapp.directive('enter', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: function ($scope, $timeout) {
            // do we have started timeout
            var timeoutStarted = false;

            // pending value of mouse state
            var pendingMouseState = false;

            $scope.changeMouseState = function (newMouseState) {
                // if pending value equals to new value then do nothing
                if (pendingMouseState == newMouseState) {
                    return;
                }
                // otherwise store new value
                pendingMouseState = newMouseState;
                // and start timeout
                startTimer();
            };

            function startTimer() {     
                // if timeout started then do nothing
                if (timeoutStarted) {
                    return;
                }

                // start timeout 10 ms
                $timeout(function () {
                    // reset value of timeoutStarted flag
                    timeoutStarted = false;
                    // apply new value
                    $scope.mouseOver = pendingMouseState;
                }, 10, true);
            }
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {
            //**********************************************
            //  bind to "mouseenter" and "mouseleave" events
            //**********************************************
            element.bind('mouseover', function (event) {
                scope.changeMouseState(true);
            });

            element.bind('mouseleave', function (event) {
                scope.changeMouseState(false);
            });

            //**********************************************
            //  watch value of "mouseOver" variable
            // or you create bindings in markup
            //**********************************************
            scope.$watch("mouseOver", function (value) {
                console.log(value);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Same thing at http://jsfiddle.net/22WgG/

Also instead

```
element.bind("mouseenter", ...);
```

and

```
element.bind("mouseleave", ...);
```

you can specify

```
<tr enter ng-mouseenter="changeMouseState(true)" ng-mouseleave="changeMouseState(false)">...</tr>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/hwnW3/